# In an interview, is it unprofessional to talk about experiences you had in online communities?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I help run a popular online writers' group. Would it be inappropriate to talk about this in an interview, seeing as the group is online? For example, if I'm asked "when as a time you disagreed with a colleague?" could I refer to a situation where I and someone else who was in charge had a conflict in this group?

Comment: What kind of job are you applying for?

Comment: The particular one I'm interviewing for at the moment is part time retail. But that's not the end of my job search by any means, so I'd also like to know how this applies in other situations. Ideally I hope to get something in data analytics eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's an issue with *appropriateness*, but there may be an issue with *relevance*.

If you're managing a remote team, it's obviously relevant. If you're managing people face-to-face, the only opinion on this that will matter is that of the interviewer.

The skills in managing remote and local teams overlap, but aren't identical. Given a choice between online and offline conflict resolution, I imagine most people would pick offline if the job is face-to-face.

If you do go with the online example, I'd be prepared to give an offline example as well.

Comment: I'd argue than communication online is harder than face-to-face because lot of things you can do on face-to-face (gesturing, a fast drawing on the keyboard) is either not possible or take more time.